# Помогите с запятыми в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Он порой дрожит забывшись сном.
Нужны ли тут запятые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения грамматики, запятая нужна, она отделяет деепричастный оборот. 
Но фраза построена так, что можно подумать, что "дрожит" — главное действие, а  "забывшись сном" — сопутствующее. Лучше сказать так:

**Забывшись сном, он порой дрожит.**

Comment: Ой-ой! ДрожЬ…….

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, Вас бросает в дрожь от моих ошибок?

Comment: Нет, ну что Вы! Я прекрасно понимаю, что это просто описка. Буковок в комментарии должно быть энное количество. Пусть будут весёленькими.

Comment: Еще исправьте "с точки".

Comment: Друзья, я вам доверяю. Можете  исправлять мои ляпы на ваш вкус.

Comment: Если допустить, что "дрожит"- главное действие- запятой не нужно?

Comment: Лея, как такое можно допустить? Сон — форма проявления дрожи(?!)

Comment: Или он дрожит и попутно еще немного спит(?!)

Comment: Дрожит, когда забывается сном)  Спасибо, я поняла, запятая нужна)

Answer (score 2):

**Он порой дрожит, забывшись сном.**
*Забывшись сном* — это [деепричастный оборот](https://5-ege.ru/sintaksicheskie-normy/), который необходимо отделить запятой.

*Так узник эллинский, **порою

Забывшись сном среди степей**,

Под скифской вьюгой снеговою

Свободой бредил золотою

И небом Греции своей.*
Ф. И. Тютчев

***Забывшись сном***, Ночь предалась покою;
Уснула, как живое существо.
Из камня Ангел создал естество.
Не веришь, тронь – заговорит с тобою.
Джованни Строцци

*И пьет Орфей настой из терпких слов,

**забывшись сном**, над лирою склоняясь

и наблюдая гладь

сиреневого Стикса.*
Владимир Эрль